# Reallocation of Array of Pointers in C++, using new and delete only

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Carray.h

```
#ifndef CARRAY_H
#define CARRAY_H

#include "Cell.h"
#include "Pirate.h"

class CArray
{
  public:
    CArray();
    ~CArray();
    int   getSize();
    Cell* get(int);
    int   add(Cell*);
  private:
    int    size;
    Cell** elements;
};

#endif
```

CArray.cc

```
CArray::CArray() : size(0)
{ 
  elements = new Cell*[size];
}

CArray::~CArray() 
{
  for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
    delete elements[i];
}

int CArray::add(Cell* cell)
{
  Cell** tmp = new Cell*[size];
  tmp = elements;
  elements = new Cell*[size+1];

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    *(elements + i) = *(tmp + i);
  }

  *(elements + size) = cell;

  delete [] tmp;

  size++;
}
```

This  last function gives a memory leak and I'm not sure as to where. All I know is that each new must be matched with a delete and each new[] with a delete[]. However testing this in valgrind and trying to delete[] elements before I reallocate elements gives me a Segmentation Fault. If someone could explain where I'm going wrong I would be a happy camper. I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find anything specific enough to solve my problem.

Comment: Please post your `CArray` class definition.

Comment: Posted, thank you for noticing

Comment: Slightly off topic: Maybe it's just me, but are you deleting element[0] in the destructor? You are using pre-incrementing in the loop, which increments the variable.. I'm not sure I'm right, it just looks suspicious :)

Answer (score 2):

You are allocating for `tmp` and then immediately losing the pointer returned to you by assigning to `tmp`:

```
Cell** tmp = new Cell*[size];
tmp = elements;
```

The lines above produce a memory leak, since the value returned by `new` is lost as soon as the second line is executed.

> All I know is that each new must be matched with a delete and each
>   new[] with a delete[].

That is not the only thing to consider.  The *value* returned by `new/new[]` must be the same *value* you use when calling `delete/delete[]`.

To fix your function, you should do this:

```
int CArray::add(Cell* cell)
{
  Cell** tmp = new Cell*[size + 1];

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    tmp[i] = elements[i];  
  tmp[size] = cell;

  ++size;
  delete [] elements;
  elements = tmp;
  return 1;
}
```

Note how the elements are copied to the `tmp` array, then it's just a matter of simply getting rid of the old memory (which is `elements`) and assign to `elements` the new data.

Also, there is another subtle bug in that you have a return value of `int`, but you didn't return anything.  Not returning a value from a function that says it returns a value is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: So I would need some sort of for loop like I used below those lines to transfer the data from elements to tmp?

Comment: Don't forget to provide a copy constructor and copy assignment operator that both make a similar copy of the `elements` to avoid leaking.  You can also use `std::copy()` instead of a manual loop to copy the elements. But if you can use STL algorithms, then you should also use `std::vector` instead and not worry about manually using `new`/`delete` at all.

Answer (score 1):

In the two first lines

```
Cell** tmp = new Cell*[size];
tmp = elements;
```

You allocate memory, take direction of new in tmp and replace pointer. So, you lost the direction of new.